# Swift Error JSONDecoder keyNotFound When trying to Create Object

Tags: arrays, json, swift

Need to create object from JSON Object from API

**JSON Response from API**

```
[
  {
    "CUSTOMER_ID": 1,
    "CUSTOMER_CODE": "123",
    "PERSONS": [
      {
        "FIRST_NAME": "Patrick",
        "MID_NAME": "A.",
        "LAST_NAME": "L."
      },
      {
        "FIRST_NAME": "Nadine",
        "MID_NAME": "N.",
        "LAST_NAME": "Ricordo"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "CUSTOMER_ID": 2,
    "CUSTOMER_CODE": "456",
    "PERSONS": [
      {
        "FIRST_NAME": "Giulio",
        "MID_NAME": "G.",
        "LAST_NAME": "A."
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "CUSTOMER_ID": 3,
    "CUSTOMER_CODE": "789",
    "PERSONS": [
      {
        "FIRST_NAME": "Vanessa",
        "MID_NAME": null,
        "LAST_NAME": "B"
      },
      {
        "FIRST_NAME": "Nadine",
        "MID_NAME": "D.",
        "LAST_NAME": "Ricordo"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

**I also created struct like below**

```
struct Customer : Codable {
    var CUSTOMER_ID: Int
    var CUSTOMER_CODE: String
    var PERSONS: Person
}

struct Person : Codable {
    var FIRST_NAME: String
    var MID_NAME: String? // can be null
    var LAST_NAME: String
}
```

**My ViewModel**

```
class CustomerListViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var customers: [CustomerViewModel] = []
    
    func getAllCustomers() {
        
        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        guard let token = defaults.string(forKey: "jsonwebtoken") else {
            return
        }
        
        Webservice().getAllCustomers(token: token) { (result) in
            switch result {
                case .success(let customers):
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.customers = customers.map(CustomerViewModel.init)
                    }
                case .failure(let error):
                    print(error.localizedDescription) // output: AppName.NetworkError error 2.
            }
        }
        
    }
    
}


struct CustomerViewModel {
    
    let customer: Customer
    
    let id = UUID()
    
    var CUSTOMER_ID: Int {
        return customer.CUSTOMER_ID
    }
    
    var CUSTOMER_CODE: String {
        return customer.CUSTOMER_CODE
    }
    
    var PERSONS: Person {
        return customer.PERSONS
    }
```

**Decoding at Webservice class**

```
class Webservice {
        
    func getAllCustomers(token: String, completion: @escaping (Result<[Customer], NetworkError>) -> Void) {
        
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://myapi") else {
            completion(.failure(.invalidURL))
            return
        }
        
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.addValue(token, forHTTPHeaderField: "access-token")
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                completion(.failure(.noData))
                return
            }
            
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
            
            do {
                let customers = try decoder.decode(Array<Customer>.self, from: data)
                print(customers)
                completion(.success(customers))
            } catch let error {
                print("[Webservice] Decoding Error")
                print(error)
                completion(.failure(.decodingError))
                return
            }
        }.resume()
    }
[...]
}
```

**ERROR**

`[Webservice] Decoding Error keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "CUSTOMER_ID", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [_JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0)], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"CUSTOMER_ID\", intValue: nil) (\"CUSTOMER_ID\"), with divergent representation cUstomerId, converted to c_ustomer_id.", underlyingError: nil))`

Later I want for example print(myCustomerViewModel.PERSONS[i].FIRST_NAME) using my ViewModel
I also need null handling if a value in my JSON is null like for example at MID_NAME of "Vanessa"

**UPDATE 1**

After deleting
`decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase`

I'm getting following error:

`keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "CUSTOMER_ID", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [_JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0)], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"CUSTOMER_ID\", intValue: nil) (\"CUSTOMER_ID\").", underlyingError: nil))`

Comment: Add the following code before the decoding to verify you get the json you expect, `let string = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)! print(string)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete this line

```
decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
```

as you actually don't convert the keys from snake case (better add CodingKeys to avoid those ugly capitalized names).

And to get rid of another error declare `PERSONS` as array

```
var PERSONS: [Person]
```

Comment: The error with PERSONS should be solved now, the error with keyNotFound still exists after even deleting this line.

Comment: I'm seeing that the new error is
`keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "CUSTOMER_ID", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [_JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0)], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"CUSTOMER_ID\", intValue: nil) (\"CUSTOMER_ID\").", underlyingError: nil))`

Comment: Then the JSON is not the real JSON. At least the JSON in the question matches the structs. Create a string from `data` and `print` it to see what you get.

Comment: But that's exactly the same JSON output that my API outputs.

Comment: Output of `print(data)` is `424 bytes`

Comment: The error says it's not. I guess you get another JSON string representing an error. No, don't print `data`, create a string with `String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!` and print that.

Comment: Output `Optional("[\n  {\n    \"id\": 1,\n    \"CUSTOMER_CODE\": \"1234\",\n    \"createdAt\": \"2022-11-20T16:42:34.000Z\",\n    \"updatedAt\": \"2022-11-20T16:42:34.000Z\"\n  },\n  {\n    \"id\": 2,\n    \"CUSTOMER_CODE\": \"213123\",\n    \"createdAt\": \"2022-11-20T17:58:23.000Z\",\n    \"updatedAt\": \"2022-11-20T17:58:23.000Z\"\n  },\n  {\n    \"id\": 3,\n    \"CUSTOMER_CODE\": \"4444\",\n    \"createdAt\": \"2022-11-20T19:34:29.000Z\",\n    \"updatedAt\": \"2022-11-20T19:34:29.000Z\"\n  }\n]")`

-----
I see there is CUSTOMER_ID and PERSONS missing...  I see I've used a wrong API url

Comment: I don't know, it' s your API.

Comment: Maybe you are calling the wrong endpoint, how can anyone but you find out why you don't get the expected data? This question has been properly answered already in my opinion and this answer should be marked as accepted and then you need to continue with this separate issue by yourself or post a new question if you can find some new information.

Comment: Thank you sooo much, after changing the api url to the correct one everything is working perfectly.